# TeamCity 8.0.4 - wait for triggered build to finish and then download it

Tags: teamcity, package, teamcity-8.0

I found a way to trigger adding package build to queue using url.
I also know how to download latest package with url, but I have a problem.
I need to download latest package after TC will finish processing build that I triggered before.
Is there any way to check if there is any build proceeding and download when it's over?
I need to do that with url, because I'm writing custom script.

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: [This looks like a similar problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11966674/tracking-build-progress-with-teamcity-rest-api) to what you have. have a look at the second answer, which is from 2014 and looks like it has details on checking build status via URL.

Comment: that's helpful - thank's!